# VBA to call values of specific selection cells to put in the subject of Email

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I select data from excel workbook and send to outlook. I need to update the below Vba code to call values of specific cells in columns (F,G,H) corresponding to my selection to put in Subject of Email , but I do not know how !

For example: Work orders need review @ Area"...." ,Field "...." , Platform"...."

[image: Sheet Data]

```
Sub Send_Selections_To_OutlookEmail()

    Dim objSelection As Excel.Range
    Dim objTempWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objTempWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim strTempHTMLFile As String
    Dim objTempHTMLFile As Object
    Dim objFileSystem As Object
    Dim objTextStream As Object
    Dim objOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNewEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Strbody As String

    
    'Set the selection
    Set objSelection = Nothing
    Set objSelection = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Selection.Copy
 
    'Paste the copied selected ranges into a temp worksheet
    Set objTempWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    Set objTempWorksheet = objTempWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 
    'Keep the values, column widths and formats in pasting
    With objTempWorksheet.Cells(1)
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With
 
    'Save the temp worksheet as a HTML file
    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strTempHTMLFile = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path & "\Temp for Excel" & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    Set objTempHTMLFile = objTempWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, strTempHTMLFile, objTempWorksheet.name, objTempWorksheet.UsedRange.Address)
    objTempHTMLFile.Publish (True)
 
    'Create a new email
    Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNewEmail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
     
    'Read the HTML file data and insert into the email body
    objNewEmail.Display
    Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strTempHTMLFile)
    Strbody = "<H5>Eng.</H5>" & "Kindly review the below item to close.<br>"
    
    objNewEmail.HTMLBody = Strbody & "<table align=""left"">" & objTextStream.ReadAll & "<br>" & "<br>" & objNewEmail.HTMLBody
    
    'You can specify the new email recipients, subjects here using the following lines:
    'objNewEmail.To = "johnsmith@datanumen.com"
    objNewEmail.Subject = " PM need review to close @"
    'objNewEmail.Send --> directly send out this email
 
    objTextStream.Close
    objTempWorkbook.Close (False)
    objFileSystem.DeleteFile (strTempHTMLFile)
            
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! "I select data from excel workbook", how many rows? When you select what is the typical range selected?

Comment: The number of rows is not fixed. typical range begin from column D , But end not fixed also

Comment: Loop through the cells and if the subject matches your criteria, grab the matching data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Niton" from stackoverflow , Helpfully create this VBA and it works :

```
Option Explicit 

Sub Append_GHIValues_To_Subject()
    
    Dim objOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNewEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Dim rwSel As Range

    Dim GValue As String
    Dim HValue As String
    Dim IValue As String
    
    Set rwSel = Selection
    
    With rwSel.EntireRow
        GValue = .Cells(6).Value
        HValue = .Cells(7).Value
        IValue = .Cells(8).Value
    End With
    
    'Create a new email
    Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNewEmail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    objNewEmail.Display
    objNewEmail.Subject = " PM need review to close @" & " " & GValue & " " & HValue & " " & IValue
            
End Sub
```